# Searching Multiple strings with 1st criteria, then searching those returned values with a different criteria and so on

Tags: vb.net

so..

I have a txt file with hundreds of sentences or strings.

I also have 4 comboboxes with options that a user can select from and
each combobox is part of a different selection criteria. They may or may not use all the comboboxes.

When a user selects an option from any combobox I use a For..Next statement to run through the txt file and pick out all the strings that contain or match whatever the user selected. It then displays those strings for the user to see, so that if they wanted to they could further narrow down the search from that point by using the 3 remaining comboboxes making it easier to find what they want.

I can achieve this by using lots of IF statements within the for loop but is that the only way?

Comment: What kind of application it is? Web  application or Windows form application? Can you share the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are other ways.  You can leverage LINQ to get rid of some of those if statements:

```
Private _lstLinesInFile As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

Private Function AddClause(ByVal qryTarget As IEnumerable(Of String), ByVal strToken As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)

    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strToken) Then

        qryTarget = qryTarget.Where(Function(ByVal strLine As String) strLine.Contains(strToken))

    End If

    Return qryTarget

End Function

Public Sub YourEventHandler()

    'Start Mock
    Dim strComboBox1Value As String = "Test"
    Dim strComboBox2Value As String = "Stack"
    Dim strComboBox3Value As String = String.Empty
    Dim strComboBox4Value As String = Nothing
    'End Mock

    If _lstLinesInFile.Count = 0 Then

        'Only load from the file once.
        _lstLinesInFile = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\Test.txt").ToList()

    End If

    Dim qryTarget As IEnumerable(Of String) = (From strTarget In _lstLinesInFile)

    'Assumes you don't have to match tokens that are split by line breaks.
    qryTarget = AddClause(qryTarget, strComboBox1Value)
    qryTarget = AddClause(qryTarget, strComboBox2Value)
    qryTarget = AddClause(qryTarget, strComboBox3Value)
    qryTarget = AddClause(qryTarget, strComboBox4Value)

    Dim lstResults As List(Of String) = qryTarget.ToList()  

End Sub
```

Keep in mind this is case sensitive so you may want to throw in some .ToLower() calls in there:

```
qryTarget = qryTarget.Where(Function(ByVal strLine As String) strLine.ToLower().Contains(strToken.ToLower()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a compound `If` statement is the simplest:

```
Dim strLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(strFilename).Split(vbCrLf)
Dim strSearchTerm1 As String = "Foo"
Dim strSearchTerm2 As String = "Bar"
Dim strSearchTerm3 As String = "Two"
Dim strSearchTerm4 As String = ""
Dim lstOutput As New List(Of String)
For Each s As String In strLines
  If s.Contains(strSearchTerm1) AndAlso
    s.Contains(strSearchTerm2) AndAlso
    s.Contains(strSearchTerm3) AndAlso
    s.Contains(strSearchTerm4) Then
    lstOutput.Add(s)
  End If
Next
```